# .click не работает в WP loop

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

Есть такой loop в WP:

```html
<?php /*Start the loop*/ ?>
    <?php $specialistquery = new WP_Query('category_name=our-specialists'); ?>
    <?php while ( $specialistquery->have_posts()) : $specialistquery->the_post()?>
    <div class="full-info clear">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        <p class="name visible"><?php the_title() ?></p>
        <div class="post-content">
          <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content' ); ?>
          <img class="close-full" src="">
        </div>
        <p class="specialization visible"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'specialization', true) ?></p>
        <p class="education visible"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'education', true) ?></p> 
        <p class="experience visible">Стаж более 25 лет</p> 
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.specialist-content').on('click','.full-info',function(){
 $(this).find('.post-content').css({'display':'inline','background':'#f1f5f5'});
 $(this).find('.specialization').css({'display':'none'});
 $(this).find('.education').css({'display':'none'});
 $(this).find('.experience').css({'display':'none'});
 $(this).find('.attachment-post-thumbnail').css({'margin':'0 30px 25px 0','width':'300px','height':'300px'});
});
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.specialist-content').on('click','.close-full',function(){
 $(this).find('.post-content').css({'display':'none','background':'none'});
 $(this).find('.specialization').css({'display':'inline'});
 $(this).find('.education').css({'display':'inline'});
 $(this).find('.experience').css({'display':'inline'});
 $(this).find('.attachment-post-thumbnail').css({'margin':'0','width':'300px','height':'300px'});
});
});
</script>
```

Немного подправил код, но теперь надо закрыть  при нажатии на изображение, но ничего не выходит. 
click close-full

Comment: Что выводит в консоли `$('.<?php echo get_the_ID() ?>')`?

Comment: нет выводит ID поста в каждой итерации свой ID в этом плане все нормально

Comment: Мои глаза. Поправтье код кто-нибудь

Comment: Было бы здорово подставить вместо php кода то, что он возвращает

Comment: Добавил ID который возвращается

Comment: Заменил `type=\"text/javascript\"` на `type="text/javascript"` и заработало. Убрал слеши лишние

Comment: немного оффтоп: зачем вешать 100 слушателей на 100 объектов, когда можно повесить один, на родителя? Вне цикла вешаем $(родитель).on('click','.full-info',function(){$(this).find('.post-content').css(...)})

Comment: Боже, идиот, спасибо большое!

Comment: @Иван Не очень понял, в силу своей необразованности, как это будет работать?

Comment: на русском про делегирование событий можно прочитать здесь: http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/On в разделе "Прямая и делегированная обработка". Кратко: вместо того, чтобы вешать 100 слушателей на 100 элементов, вешается слушатель события на их общего родителя, который отслеживает клики на указанных "потомках". Получается то же самое (в вашем случае), но код проще (не нужно в цикле один и тот же код писать) и 1 слушатель вместо 100.

Comment: и $('.post-content-334') такое указание конечной цели можно заменить на общую конструкцию. Ведь все эти элементы можно объединить по признаку: они имеют класс .post-content и находятся внутри элемента, на котором срабатывает клик. Пишем просто $(this).find('.post-content').css‌​(...) - внутри блока, по которому кликнули ищем элемент с нужным классом. При каждом клике будет нужный элемент, а код одинаковый.

Comment: Спасибо большое за объяснение!